# Custom User Model creates additional groups and permissions table

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 2.2

I've created a Custom User model by inheriting from `AbstractUser`. Along with it, I also create a `UserManager`.

```
# ./settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'core.apps.AuthConfig'
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'
```

```
# ./core/models.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
```

```
# ./core/managers.py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email field is required')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

When I run:

- `./manage.py makemigrations`
- `./manage.py migrate`

I get additional tables created in my database related groups and permissions.

[image]

What's the purpose of this? Am I doing something wrong?

I tried creating a group in Django admin and assigned a few permissions to it. Only the `auth_group` and `auth_group_permissions` table are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those models come from ManyToMany fields defined in **PermissionsMixin**, which is inherited by **AbstractUser**, which is inherited by your custom **User** model.

```
groups = models.ManyToManyField(
    Group,
    verbose_name=_('groups'),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_(
        'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
        'granted to each of their groups.'
    ),
    related_name="user_set",
    related_query_name="user",
)
user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    Permission,
    verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
    blank=True,
    help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
    related_name="user_set",
    related_query_name="user",
)
```

As can be seen here, **groups** keep the relationship between a user and a group, and **user_permissions** keep specific permissions for a user, directly related to user (not through groups).

If you do not want these, you can define your user model based on **AbstractBaseUser** class.